# How to Compute the payoff of Var Swaps, which I have replicated

Tags: options, black-scholes, derivatives, variance, replication

I used Derman(1999) method, to calculate the fixed Kvar for Variance Swaps using actual option price data. The first Pic Shows the outcome. (ignore the 0s).[image: I plot the sqrt of Swap rate]
[image]

Now the profit and loss of short var swaps is totally wrong, the Sharpe ratio is 2.[image: Makes no major losses in 2007]

I want to ask how the realized Var is actually computed, to calculate payoff. Do I need to annualise it, currently I multiply RealisedVar with 365/45. as Maturity is 45 days. P&L is depends on the multiplication factor. Kvar is not anualised so why should realized var be?

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_swap#cite_note-FINCAD-1

Comment: What makes you say that the P&L of being short a Varswap is "totally wrong"? What are you comparing it to?

Comment: It just keeps going up. A huge loss was made in 2007. According to a figure in Asset Management by andrew Ang, this profit and loss is not correct. I should have a large loss. Also, such profits are not reasonable

Comment: Have you read this: http://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/[JP%20Morgan]%20Variance%20Swaps.pdf